# Render object attributes on the same site with click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, click

There's this button / link in my web app. It's a button for a pizza - margherita with price, ingredients, and category, all already loaded to the db. Clicking this button loads the item's id to params, which is then used to find the object.

I want the click to launch the following chain of events:

1. Load the id
2. Find the object by id
3. Instantly render the object and its attributes **in adjacent div on the same site**.

Is this possible without JavaScript, just Ruby on Rails?
I am stuck at point 3. I have an idea, but incomplete. Please, give me a hint.

PS. My idea is to render views for index and show in separate divs next to one another.

@NickM, I added your code and it's throwing `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error, pointing at `respond_to do |format|` in `show_pizza` method.

Here's my `pizzas/index.html.haml`:

```
%h1= t :all_pizzas
- @pizzas.each do |pizza|
  = render pizza
.orders
  %h1 Orders
```

And `pizzas/_pizza.html.haml`:

```
%tr
  = link_to pizza.name, show_a_pizza_path(pizza.id), :method => :post
  %br/
```

I am getting this error upon clicking the link in `_pizza.html.erb`. My `show_pizza.js` is now:

```
pizza_div = $("#orders");
pizza_div.html( "<%= j render( :partial => 'pizzas/pizza', :locals => { :pizza => @pizza } ) %>" );
```

What am I missing? Sorry, I don't know js.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. When the link is clicked you will need to either render another page or handle the data returned by the controller with Javascript. The best option would be to set up an action that responds with JSON and parse what you get back on the front end.

Even after your P.S. you will have to handle the response from the server with Javascript, unless you are okay with rendering a new page. You need to post some code, preferably routes and controller action. This would also work:

```
<%= link_to("Show Pizza", show_a_pizza_path(@pizza.id), :method => :post, :data => {:remote => true}) %>
```

routes.rb

```
post 'show_pizza/:id' => "pizzas#show_pizza", :as => :show_a_pizza
```

pizzas_controller.rb

```
def show_pizza
  @pizza = Pizza.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

views/pizzas/show_pizza.js

```
pizza_div = $("#the_name_of_your_div");
pizza_div.html( "<%= j render( :partial => 'pizzas/pizza', :locals => { :pizza => @pizza } ) %>" );
```

and then put the pizza markup in /views/pizzas/_pizza.html.erb

Comment: Well, it didn't solve my problem, but even your short answer alone was useful ;)

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. I forgot to add :data => {:remote => true}
Are you really working with a .jd file? Never seen that with Rails